# MS-Oracle ODBC Driver Function Sequence Error

Tags: oracle, odbc, ms-access-2007

I'm using the Microsoft-Oracle ODBC Driver to access an Oracle database in MS Access, but on about half of my linked tables, I get a [Function Sequence Error] whenever I try to pull up the Datasheet view.  I've looked around for alternative drivers, but no luck.

Does anyone know how to stop getting these function sequence errors?  And if I need a new driver, could you provide a link if possible to a download site?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  The problem was that the Microsoft-Oracle ODBC driver mistakenly converted Oracle's CLOB (Character Large Object) fields into mere Text[255 char] fields in Access.  And then Access freaked out whenever it tried to render these CLOBS with more than 255 characters.

So I just excluded those CLOB fields from all my queries and migration tables.  It does mean that I can't migrate over fields like "Description" or "Notes," but at least I can migrate over the primary keys and relationships.  That's good enough for me, for now.

Comment: This was helpful.  In my case, we had linked an Oracle table with a "TIMESTAMP" field that Access set as a Text(255) field.  I could not open the linked table in Access, but an Access query that selected all but the TIMESTAMP fields worked fine.