# HY010 Oracle ODBC Function sequence error in SSIS?

Tags: oracle, ssis, odbc, etl, ssis-2008

I created an SSIS package to copy data from one Oracle table to another Oracle table. Each table is in a different database.

I'm getting this error for every single column of the source table:

> ERROR [HY010] [Oracle][ODBC]Function sequence error

This is the screenshot.

[image]

I have no idea what this means. I've also researched but I haven't seen anything that has helped me.

How can I fix this? I did read that an alternative is to create a linked server.

I wanted to add that the ODBC driver was created with a [relatively recent Oracle 12 driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exVPk.png), so I'm not sure why `VARCHAR2` columns would not be supported.

Also wanted to point out that the Windows server where the Oracle DB is 64-bit (Windows Server 2008) and Visual Studio 2008 (where the SSIS package is created) is 32-bit. That's why the driver has "_32" at the end.

Comment: Why not using OLE DB?

Comment: I don't have the choice of an ODBC data provider with OLE DB.

Comment: What is the columns metadata? if VARCHAR2 what is the columns length?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [following documentation](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Function-sequence-error-with-ODBC):

> The error occurs when ODBC functions are called out of the order required by the ODBC Specification.
>   The error can also occur if an ODBC function call returns an error and the application continues making ODBC calls that require the previous ODBC call to succeed.

I think you should check that all columns data types are supported by the ODBC driver.

**Similar questions**

- [MS-Oracle ODBC Driver Function Sequence Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347920/ms-oracle-odbc-driver-function-sequence-error)

---

### Update 1

You can refer to the following link to learn more about supported data types:

- [Oracle® Database Gateway for ODBC User's Guide - Data Type Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15817_01/server.111/e10311/apa.htm)

Note that in the link above they mentioned that:

> If a table contains a column whose data type is not supported by Oracle Database Gateway for ODBC, the column information is not returned to the Oracle database.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The ODBC was created with a relative recent driver "oraclient12home1_32", so it doesn't make sense that a b unch of `VARCHAR2` columns would not be supported. https://i.stack.imgur.com/exVPk.png

Comment: @fdkgfosfskjdlsjdlkfsf what is the columns length?